# Visual Studio docker-compose build context

Tags: docker, visual-studio, .net-core, docker-compose, github-actions

When adding container orchastrator support (docker-compose) to a .NET Core Web API project with a dependency on some project library the following folder structure is created

```
├── Solution
│   ├── API.Project
|   |   ├──  API.Project.csproj
|   |   ├──  Dockfile
|   |   
|   ├── Library.project
|   |   ├──  Library.project.csproj
|   |   
|   ├── docker-compose.yaml
```

As you can see the library project is outside the Dockerfile context. If I build an image in my Github Action pipeline with docker/build-push-action@v2 (https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-and-push-docker-images) it can't find the library project. If I move the Dockerfile to the Solution folder and build the image and run a container the visual studio debugger won't attach, but the container does run. However, when I make a http request to the container a null pointer exception is logged in the container logs (also in a container from the github action image). How do I build an docker image with a folder structure like this example? I would prefer too keep the Dockerfile inside the API.project folder.

Comment: Have you tried using parent dir as build context?

Comment: @frennky yes when I do that the container logs a null pointer exception when I make a http request, but the app works just fine if i keep the dockerfile in the original location

Comment: Can you show your Dockerfile and workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With docker/build-push-action@v2 you can specify the context and the location of the docker file like so:

```
name: Build and push
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
    with:
      context: .
      file: API.Project/Dockerfile
      push: true
      tags: user/app:latest
```

This allows you to include files in the parent folder of the Dockerfile.

The null pointer exception I received when moving my Dockerfile to the parent folder had to do with a dependency on System.Security.Cryptography, but I didn't have to solve it, because specifying the docker build context and keeping the dockerfile inside the API.project folder fixed my issues